# Java recursive loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to stop this recursive loop in Java.

I have made a program which prints numbers like
Output :1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1

It's like creating a wave of increasing and decreasing numbers. But i want to stop, when it gets more than the length of the string. Can anyone give an alternate way.

```
boolean isboolean = true;

public void recursive(int data, String s) {
    int counter = 0;

    Loop1:
    while (isboolean) {
        counter++;
        data = data + 1;
        System.out.print(data + " ");
        if (data > 5) {
            isboolean = false;
        }
        if (counter > s.length()) break Loop1;
    }
    Loop2:
    while (!isboolean) {
        data = data - 1;
        System.out.print(data + " ");
        if (data == 0) {
            isboolean = true;
        }
    }
    recursive(data, s);
}
```

I want to stop this wave of numbers when it gets more than String s length.
And prints output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
but stops, when it's more than string length.

Comment: What is `isboolean` and where does it get defined?

Comment: @AK47 why return anything if the method is `void`?

Comment: Why are you using labeled loops when you don't have nested loops?

Comment: What do you mean by _when it gets more than the length of the string._ IF you want to break the recursiveness do a `if (data>s.length()) return;` Place it as the first line in the add method and it will break.

Comment: @loannis Barakos: value of data is changing after every cycle, so used a counter variable

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz, yes removed that, this is the first time i have posted, so clearly don't have too much idea

Comment: @ZahidAnsari No problem. Check my answer too!

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz : Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

With few corrections:

1- declare counter outside

2- make length conditions to both loops

3- stop recursion when length reaches

4- counter should be incremented in both loops.

5- no need for labeled loop now.

```
boolean isboolean= true;
int counter = 0;

public void add(int data, String s) {

    //Loop1:
    while (isboolean && counter <= s.length()) {
        counter++;
        data = data + 1;
        System.out.print(data + " ");
        if (data > 5) {
            isboolean = false;
        }
    }
    //Loop2:
    while (!isboolean && counter<= s.length()) {
        counter++;
        data = data - 1;
        System.out.print(data + " ");
        if (data == 0) {
            isboolean = true;
        }
    }
    if (counter<=s.length())
        add(data, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your needs you don't need a recursive loop, this will do what you want

So for your needs you would put `min` as 0 `max` as 6 and `offset` as 0:

```
private static void numberWave(String text, int min, int max, int offset) {
    for (int i = min+offset; i < text.length()+min+offset ; i++) {
        int deltaMX = max-min;
        int counterMod = ((i)%(deltaMX));
        int upWards = min+counterMod+1;
        int downWards = min+(deltaMX-counterMod-1);
        boolean counterPart = (i)%(deltaMX*2)<deltaMX;
        System.out.print((counterPart?upWards:downWards)+" ");
    }
}
```

---

Input: `numberWave("Hello world" , 0 , 6 , 0 )`

Output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to pass the `counter` value rather than using an error-prone global variable for `counter` *(because it will result in incorrect values if called more than once)*. And secondly, you can simplify both of your loops into a single loop:

```
public void recursive(int data, String s, int counter) {
    boolean increment = true;

    while (counter <= s.length()) {
        counter++;
        if (increment)
            data += 1;
        else
            data -= 1;
        System.out.print(data + " ");
        if (increment && data > 5) {
            increment = false;
        } else if (!increment && data == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (counter <= s.length()) {
        recursive(data, s, counter);
    }
}
```

And call your method like this:

```
recursive(0, "abcdefghijklmno", 1);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3
```